# Apple Script to disconnect wireless keyboard in menu bar on the top of the screen

Tags: macos, applescript, disconnect

I'm trying to try disconnecting my wireless keyboard using Applescript.

I came up with this script with UI browser:

```
activate application "SystemUIServer"
tell application "System Events"
tell application process "SystemUIServer"
    click menu item "Disconnect" of menu 1 of menu item "Apple Wireless Keyboard of menu 1 of menu bar item 2 of menu bar 1
end tell
end tell
```

However, I get getting the following error:

```
"System Events got an error: Can’t get menu 1 of menu bar item 2 of menu bar 1 of application process "SystemUIServer". Invalid index."
```

What did I do wrong here, and how can I fix it?

Comment: This shouldn't even compile; `...menu item "Apple Wireless Keyboard (missing quotation)`. Or is it a typo?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. Make sure that it selects the correct menu bar item

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "SystemUIServer"
        tell menu bar item 2 of menu bar 1
            click
            tell menu item "Apple Wireless Mouse" of front menu
                click
                tell first menu item of front menu
                    click
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```